# Interaction between categorical variables with multiple levels in R

Tags: r, categorical-data

In the dataset I need to analyse, I need to look at whether the effect of people's profession (3 categories) on their scores on a test (I have already tested for this effect and found one) differs across levels of a second categorical variable (whether they work at home, in person, or a mixture). I'm struggling to wrap my head around how to do this in R...

Comment: Would a two-way anova be appropriate for what you want to know ?  Would an interaction plot like the following be helpful  ?  [i0.wp.com/appsilon.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/4-2.png](https://i0.wp.com/appsilon.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/4-2.png)

Comment: How about a regression?